# Make an image view adjust its height to match the height of its image when the image is scaled down due to the content mode

Tags: ios, uiimageview, autolayout, interface-builder, aspect-fit

I have an image view that is constrained in a way so that its left, right and upper edge are pinned to its superview and its bottom edge has a fixed spacing to the label below. It doesn't have any width or height constraints so it's supposed to get its height from its image's intrinsic size. The content mode is set to `Aspect Fit`.

This works great if the image has a smaller or equal width as the image view (case 1 and 2, see images below). However, if the image has a width that exceeds the width of its containing image view I run into a problem (case 3):

The image is scaled down as expected so that its width matches the image view's width. **But the image view doesn't update its height accordingly**, leaving white spaces above and below. I understand that the image view still obtains its height from the image's *original* height. But due to the content mode the image's height is now a lot smaller and I want the image view to adjust its height to match the image's *actual* height.

I'm looking for a neat solution that works for each of the three cases, preferably one that works with `IB_DESIGNABLE` views as well. Any ideas?

### Case 1

**intrinsic width < frame width**

[image: intrinsic width < frame width]

### Case 2

**intrinsic width = frame width**

[image: intrinsic width = frame width]

### Case 3

**intrinsic width > frame width**

[image: intrinsic width > frame width]

Answer (score 1):

You can create an extension on `UIImageView` in following manner:

```
extension UIImageView {
    @IBInspectable var shouldAdjustHeight: Bool {
        get {
            return self.frame.size.height == self.adjustedHeight;
        }
        set {
            if newValue {
                if !shouldAdjustHeight {
                    let newHeight = self.adjustedHeight

                    // add constraint to adjust height
                    self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
                        item:self, attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.Height,
                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
                    toItem:nil, attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute,
                    multiplier:0, constant:newHeight))
            }
        }
        else {
            let newHeight = self.adjustedHeight
            // create predicate to find the height constraint that we added
            let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %d && %K == %f", "firstAttribute", NSLayoutAttribute.Height.rawValue, "constant", newHeight)
            // remove constraint
            self.removeConstraints(self.constraints.filter{ predicate.evaluateWithObject($0) })
        }
    }
}

var adjustedHeight: CGFloat {
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
    let deviceScaleFactor = screenWidth/self.bounds.size.width
    return CGFloat(ceilf(Float(deviceScaleFactor * AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect((self.image?.size)!, self.bounds).size.height))) // deviceScaleFactor multiplied with the image size for the frame
    // I am using size class in my XIB with value as (Any,Any) and I was not getting correct frame values for a particular device so I have used deviceScaleFactor.
    // You can modify above code to calculate newHeight as per your requirement
}
}
```

After adding above extension you can set the property in Interface-builder as shown below.

[image]

On setting this property, a height constraint will be added to your `imageView`. ***The calculation of `adjustedHeight` may not be very neat in my solution, so you can look into it further.***

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @san. Can you explain what you're trying to achieve with the `deviceScaleFactor`? I don't see how the screen size is related to the problem. I'd also rather not add a constraint to a view inside a setter method as it will create a new constraint each time the setter is called. So if I call `view.shouldAdjustHeight = true` three times in a row I'll add three (equal) constraints to it and they will never be removed, even when setting `view.shouldAdjustHeight = false`.

Comment: @Mischa, I was not getting the correct frames for `UIImageView`, so I used `deviceScaleFactor`. I am not sure why I was not getting the correct values of frames, thats why I told you that calculation may not be very neat but it suits in the way you are using your `UIImageView`. I have updated answer. Added check to not add constraint if height is already adjusted. Also added code to remove constraint when you set `imageView.shouldAdjustHeight = false`